# How do I print the characters of a String variable in a diagonal line?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

How can I take a `String` variable and print it's contents in a diagonal line downward? Preferably using a `for` or `while` loop.

This is the code I have now, which doesn't work as intended:

```
String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a string");

for(int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
   {
      System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
   }
```

This outputs `str` in a line downwards, but not diagonal. How can I make it look like this:

```
E
 X
  A
   M
    P
     L
      E
```

Comment: Instead of printing just the char, print `i` spaces using `print()` and then the char using `println()`.

Comment: indention ignores intention, I would say ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one more loop to add proper amount of spaces equal to `i` before your character.

```
       for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            for (int spacesCount = 0; spacesCount<i; spacesCount++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
        }
```

Comment: Works great, but I have only one more issue - is there a way to avoid having an `Exception in thread "main": String index out of range: 7` at the end of it?

Comment: @salamander This doesn't throw an exception. The error is in your original code (`i <= str.length()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        printDiagonal("hello");
    }
    public static void printDiagonal(String s)
    {
        String holdSpace = "";
        while (s.length() > 0)
        {
            String c = s.substring(0,1);
            if(s.length() > 0) 
            {
                s = s.substring(1);
            }
            holdSpace += " ";
            System.out.println(holdSpace + c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it